# I want to show real time data fetched by the REST api on the Frontend of the application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, ethereum

I have a list of transactions that are generated in seconds, I am using a wrapper to get these transactions so I made a rest api to get the transactions according to the no. But in the mean time the transaction will get generated more so how do I show the recent on as they generate continuously .

I want to create a Block Explorer on the private Ethereum blockchain using node.js as backend and angular.js as frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You could use here Websockets.

For example Socket.io - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Here is Socket.io compoenent for Angular: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

So when your transactions are generated, you will send Push message to client, and client will update it's transaction list.

Comment: from past one day i am trying to integrate the sockets in the rest api but these are not working . Do you give a sample which uses angular.js as frontend , node.js as backend and these sockets takes data from the rest api call  . please help me to sort it out  -- thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most common approach here, id you have control of contract mods, is to include event emitters for every important state change. This exposes your contract transactions in a detailed (even indexable) and inexpensive way.

On the client, you can use event watchers. This are easily configured with AngularJS. When events arrive, they invoke callbacks. You can do what you need to support the UI or offchain storage in the callback.

For example, you can append a row to an array in to Angular's view model. Angular does a good jub of updating the view when the data in the model as changed. So, a live updated display of transaction events as they arrive is quite feasible and not especially difficult.

Hope it helps.